# How can I integrate Razorpay callback with Django, considering the CSRF protection issue,

Tags: python, django, ajax, razorpay, csrf-token

How can I integrate Razorpay callback with Django, considering the CSRF protection issue, \

When using csrf_exempt for a view in Django, why does it prevent me from accessing the request.session?

nd are there alternative ways to implement it securely?

i tried to implement razorpay in my ecommerce application in django. after payment process callback function executes then i want to update the order and payment table if payment is successfull . i want to get the user id from session but becouse csrf exempt requst.session is not working. if csrf exemt is not given there will be crrf error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.